# Implementing a timelock inside token contract

Tags: erc-20

I am trying to learn how to make my own token.  I want to add a timelock so that tokens that are purchased can not be sold until a specific time.  How would I go about this?  I have very very little coding knowledge, so I am pretty lost.  I watched a video on youtube and got this code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract J4RK0FF is ERC20 {
    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) public ERC20("J4RK0FF", "J4RK") {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
    }

}
```

So if this works as a basic unmodified contract, how can I add a timelock feature to it?  Thanks in advance, sorry if I sound stupid, I have no idea what I am doing

Comment: Check the online manual at https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/ or later version. Then under "Units and Globally Available Variables" there is a block.timestamp variable. You can set a contract variable representing some time in the future, and check if block.timestamp > timelock from within your transfer() function.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a `mapping (address => uint256) timelock` where for each account you specify the timestamp when the tokens will be unlocked.

Then you can add more complexity instead of specifying a single timestamp use an array of dates allowing partials unlocks if you purchase tokes at different times.